# OpenCV (Python) face detection program not terminating

Tags: python, opencv

I have been writing a face detection program in python using OpenCV. It is working fine, but the **program is not terminating after closing the window in which faces are detected.**
I have tried `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` and `sys.exit(0)` also, but nothing is working. I can't find any solution in the internet. 
I am using python 3.8 and openCV 4.2.0.
Below is my code

```
import cv2
import sys

# Get user supplied values
imagePath = "../training_images/1/bla.jpg"
cascPath = "../HaarCascade/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"

# Create the haar cascade
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)

# Read the image
image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Detect faces in the image
faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
    gray,
    scaleFactor=1.1,
    minNeighbors=5,
    minSize=(30, 30),
    flags = cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
)

print("Found {0} faces!".format(len(faces)))

# Draw a rectangle around the faces
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow("Faces found", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
sys.exit(0)
```

Please help me.

Comment: its working perfectly for me.. what exact problem are you facing?

Comment: the program is not stoping itself. It is running indefinitely. I have to restart my ide or open a new terminal window to rerun my program.

Comment: you have to close the opened image or press a key to close that window only then the code will stop.

Comment: It's not stopping even after closing the opened image.